# Finding a specific character with strings of text then changing the formatting of the specific character only

Tags: excel, vba, replace, formatting

**Requirement** 
I have an excel sheet with hundreds of rows and columns.  Each cell is filled with random character that are times new roman, size 10, regular.
I need to find a single character "·" that is randomly placed in some cells and not in others.
Once I find this character I need to change the format to symbol, size 9, and bold.

**Problem**
I cannot use the "find all" and "replace all" feature because that changes the entire cell format.  How do I write a code to find and replace/change the "·" symbol format?  I am very amateur with VBA.

Here's what I have attempted, but it does not work.

```
 Sub bnm()
     With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "·"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "·"
        .Name = "Symbol"
        .FontStyle = "bold"
        .Size = 9
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
            Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    End With
End Sub
```

Please help!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be prettier, but it works:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim firstRange As Range
    Dim currentRange As Range
    Set firstRange = Cells.Find(What:="·", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False)
    Set currentRange = firstRange
    While Not currentRange Is Nothing
        Dim val As String
        Dim lastIndex As Integer
        val = currentRange.Value
        lastIndex = InStr(lastIndex + 1, val, "·")
        While lastIndex <> 0
            With currentRange.Characters(Start:=lastIndex, Length:=1).Font
                .Name = "Symbol"
                .Size = 9
            End With
            lastIndex = InStr(lastIndex + 1, val, "·")
        Wend
        Set currentRange = Cells.FindNext(After:=currentRange)
        If firstRange = currentRange Then
            Set currentRange = Nothing
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

A limitation is that this only works if the formatting doesn't work if the cell value is determined via a formula for example a cell containing `="test: " & "·"` cannot have special formatting for the `·`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work no matter if the text strings are pure strings, or if they are the result of a formula or concatenation.  If the latter, the macro converts it to a text string first, else differential formatting cannot be applied:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceReformat()
    Dim c As Range, r As Range
    Dim sToFind As String
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
sToFind = Chr(183)
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

With r
    Set c = .Find(What:=Chr(183), After:=r(.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=False)
   If Not c Is Nothing Then
    c.Value = c.Text  'must be a text string in order to apply character level formatting
    sFirstAddress = c.Address
        J = InStr(c.Text, sToFind)
        Do
            With c.Characters(J, 1).Font
                .Name = "Symbol"
                .Size = 9
                .Bold = True
            End With
            J = InStr(J + 1, c.Text, sToFind)
        Loop Until J = 0
      Do
        Set c = .FindNext(c)
        If c.Address <> sFirstAddress Then
          c.Value = c.Text
          J = InStr(c.Text, sToFind)
          Do
            With c.Characters(J, 1).Font
                .Name = "Symbol"
                .Size = 9
                .Bold = True
            End With
            J = InStr(J + 1, c.Text, sToFind)
          Loop Until J = 0
        End If
      Loop Until c.Address = sFirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```